# PHP file upload size is limited after changing upload_max_filesize on php.ini

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, file-upload

I am creating an online gallery with upload function. I use PHP to upload the images and store it in mysql database. It seems that it does not allow me to upload file size more than 64KB.

The following is my HTML code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label>
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

upload.php code

```
<?php

//file properties
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
    {
        echo "Please select an image";
    }
    else
    {
        $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image = file_get_contents($image);
        $image = base64_encode($image);
        saveimage($name,$image);
    }
}
displayimage();
function saveimage($name,$image){
        $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
        mysql_select_db("brandon",$con);
        $qry = "insert into store(name,image) values('$name','$image')";
        $result = mysql_query($qry,$con);
        if($result){
            echo "<br/> Image uploaded";
        }else{
            echo "<br/> Image not uploaded";
        }
    }
//display image
function displayimage()
{
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
    mysql_select_db("brandon",$con);
    $qry="select * from store";
    $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].' "> ';
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

on my database I have setup a table with 3 columns(id,name,image). ID is auto increment and primary. Name is TEXT and image is LONGBLOB.

I am using PHPstorm with PHP version 5.6.3. Xampp version is 3.2.1. Others suggest to increase the `upload_max_limit` on `php.ini` but it is not working for me. I have changed it to as following

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize=128M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size=128M
```

With the max_memory set to 128M and 60s timeout.

It all goes smooth if I upload a small image file but if I upload a large image file, it goes as following

- takes me to a blank page(echo function not executed but displays previously uploaded images)
- when I try to access another php file, it loads endlessly.(it says waiting for localhost on the bottom left corner of google chrome)
- when I try to access another php file, it shows '502 bad gateway'

Please help and thanks in advance

Edit 1: The debugger, apache and mysql error logs shows no error. I restarted XAMPP, PHPStorm and my Chrome browser in order to get it to a working state again (which allows me to upload small image files and execute php files instead of endless loading and 502 bad gateway)

Edit 2: Solved! I tried launching it from localhost instead of the autolaunch from PHPStorm. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the `php.ini` file did you restart Xampp? It won't take affect until that happens.
Also, check your PHP and Apache error logs regarding the bad gateway error, that might give you some more detail as to what's going on.

Comment: Added Edit 1. No luck.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mention the PHP log, maybe that's what you meant by "debugger"?
Another thing I would try is turning up the logging level on Apache to "debug", you should get a lot more information. Add to your virtual host config file:
`LogLevel notice`
See [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) for more detail.
If no luck there, it might be worth trying a reinstall of Xampp or testing on another server or virtual instance.